# Get heading from meta key without multiple wp_queries

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to accomplish this without the use of multiple queries. Is it possible ?

I have a custom post type set up with custom fields (Using advanced custom fields).

Here is my scenario as is now. (demo post type and fields so you get the idea)

```
    'post_type'   => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'position',
            'value' => 'driver',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
```

This will print as:

Driver

*Image*
Name of one driver
Contact info

And then a new loop here to filter out other position. Lets say managers.

```
    'post_type'   => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'position',
            'value' => 'manager',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
```

Managers

*Image*
Name of manager
Contact info.

So my question is this, can i make one loop print header for each value of meta_query one time and list the children under it ?

Or am i stuck with multiple loops ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey By using  `get_post_meta()` you can simply fetch the meta value

Example-

```
$key_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key', true );
// check if the custom field has a value
if( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) {
  echo $key_1_value;
}
```

I think it work fine.

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for. This will just get me the meta key for each item in loop.